# Singularly inappropriate closure?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, close-reasons, reopen-closed

I came across this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50422947/is-this-true-exceptions-do-not-occur-at-compile-time):

Title:

> Is this true?: Exceptions do not occur at compile time

Body:

> Is this true?: Exceptions do not occur at compile time, a compilation error is not an Exception. Explain please.

I closed as DUP to this existing [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/912334/differences-between-exception-and-error). Another user re-opened, and now I am simply not sure about the optimal handling of it.

Comment: I think https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9471837/what-is-the-difference-between-run-time-error-and-compiler-error is a more appropriate dupe here.. OP seems confused with compile and runtime issues

Comment: The question seems very poor. I'd be reluctant to apply a dupe hammer in these cases (even if I had Mjölnir).

Comment: I agree with @EJP, I think the duplicate was innapropriate. I reckon the optimal way of handling these situations is to ask here if you really disagree with the decision - which you have done!

Comment: @E_net4 There is no close reason "because too poor" ;-)

Comment: There's always downvote and closing -> other I suppose.

Comment: There is a "unclear what you're asking" (but don't abuse it. For poorly formatted questions a DV is enough)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That definitely was an inappropriate dupe target. The question asks about compilation errors. The dupe target asks about instances of `Error` thrown at run-time. That's something else entirely.

When a question is on topic, closed as a duplicate, and none of the answers are relevant to the question being asked, re-opening the question is the right thing to do.

The question was not particularly high quality, but not obviously bad either<sup>*</sup>, and didn't need closure for some other reason, so in this particular case, there was nothing else you needed to do. You made a mistake in closing the question, and that mistake had been rectified.

<sub><sup>*</sup> By not obviously bad, I mean none of the regular close reasons apply. If you feel the question is bad in that it should be downvoted, that is your right, but that should be independent of whether it should be closed.</sub>

---

What worries me is that judging by the comment you left on the question, you seem to think closing questions as duplicates is some sort of punishment that is important to inflict on low-quality questions, that even if the dupe target is useless to the OP, it's more important to leave the question closed than it is to allow the OP to receive an answer to the question asked. That is not what it is for. I hope I am misinterpreting your comment there, but if not, please do not do that.

Comment: Soiry, which comment are you referring to? I see dup closing as dup closing, nothing else.

Comment: @GhostCat I am referring to "@EJP also true, but then instead of re-opening ... as said: I usually spend my time looking for better/additional DUPs. Anyway, time to clean up now." Re-opening the question was better than leaving it closed as a duplicate of something unhelpful. Sure, finding a good dupe target beats both, but that takes time, and during that time, the question should not remain closed for a bogus reason.

Comment: @GhostCat This comment was also a clumsy attempt to shift the responsibility elsewhere. It is yours alone.

Comment: I know your stance towards high quality, therefore I was wondering why you would re-open that question and then leave it like that. The answer by hvd gives good reasons though.